# Crosscompilation GCC toolchain cannot find stdlib.h

Tags: gcc, cmake, cross-compiling, arm64, toolchain

I am trying to cross compile for a **Jetson nano** (`aarch64`) using my `x86_64` PC. I am using the [toolchain provided by nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads#?search=tool%20chain&tx=$product,jetson_tx2,jetson_nano) (GCC Tool Chain for 64-bit BSP). Right now I am stuck with the toolchain not being able to find `stdlilb.h`

```
In file included from <build dir path>/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/time.h:53:0,
                 from <build dir path>/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from <build dir path>/src/test_cpp/src/listener.cpp:1:
<build dir path>/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/platform.h:37:41: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdlib.h> // getenv, _dupenv_s
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

My toolchain is in `gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/` directory. `find -name stdlib.h -type f` gives me

```
./gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h
./gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h
./gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.8.5/tr1/stdlib.h
```

Why is the compiler unable to find `stdlib`? How do I show it to the compiler?

---

**P.S.** I did not want to make this question unnecessarily long. If needed, a full description of what I am trying to do and the errors is explained [here in my question asked in nvidia forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cross-compile-my-ros-package-for-nvidia-jetson-tx2/142926/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the toolchain include directory with `include_directories` solved the problem

```
include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM ${MY_BUILD_DIRECTORY}/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/)
```